# How to get rid of points of interests on Google Maps for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, sdk, maps

is it possible to get rid of automatically assigned by Google (SDK for iOS) points of interest such as: schools, companies etc., on the map? Some of them are marked on the screenshot attached below. [image: marked useless places]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know a way to do that with the google maps API. I'd recommend to use MapKit instead.

There you could use the `showsPointsOfInterest` method to set wether the points-of-interest should be visible or not.

[Documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/showsPointsOfInterest)

> When this property is set to true, the map displays icons and labels
>   for restaurants, schools, and other relevant points of interest. The
>   default value of this property is true.

Comment: The solution you gave is for MapKit, my application uses Google Maps.

Comment: I have switched to MapKit, surprisingly it is a great alternative way to deal with maps so your answer was useful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For google maps you can hide using json styling

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/hiding-features

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit later, but the solution is:

1. declare a map style with json string in Objective-c string:
   ···

   static NSString *const kMapStyle = @"["
   @"  {"
   @"    "featureType": "poi","
   @"    "elementType": "all","
   @"    "stylers": ["
   @"      {"
   @"        "visibility": "off""
   @"      }"
   @"    ]"
   @"  },"
   @"  {"
   @"    "featureType": "transit","
   @"    "elementType": "labels.icon","
   @"    "stylers": ["
   @"      {"
   @"        "visibility": "off""
   @"      }"
   @"    ]"
   @"  }"
   @"]";

···

2. apply this style to the map object:
   ···

   NSError *error;
   GMSMapStyle *style = [GMSMapStyle styleWithJSONString:kMapStyle error:&error];
   if (style) {
   _mapView.mapStyle = style;
   }

···

You can find more detail here: [hiding map features](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/hiding-features)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible now. Here's are the docs:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/style-reference

You can basically use the google provided [styling wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com). Make the changes you want from the wizard. When you click finish it will give you a JSON.

[image]

Add the JSON into your project then you can use something like this

```swift
extension GMSMapView {
func newMapStyle() {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mapStyle", withExtension: "json") {
            self.mapStyle = try? GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: url)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way:

```
mapView.pointOfInterestFilter = .excludingAll
```